# providing a hostname to name option in file loader breaks compilation

Tags: webpack

build compilation does not work :

```
 λ npm run build

> typescript-sass-modules@0.1.0 build C:\Users\cypri\projets\typescript-sass-modules-boilerplate
> node scripts/build.js

Creating an optimized production build...
Starting type checking and linting service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
ts-loader: Using typescript@2.8.1 and C:\Users\cypri\projets\typescript-sass-modules-boilerplate\tsconfig.json
No valid rules have been specified
```

stuck here.

How to reproduce :

add a file loader to a webpack.config.prod.js like following:

```
{ 
    loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
    exclude: [/\.js$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
    options: { 
         name: 'http://test-vad/build/static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
    }
},
```

expected behaviour :

build works, hostname prepended to files urls

**Notice** : removing the hostname works, it is not related to the error 'no valid rules have been specified" because I have it when the build works too.

Other relevant information:

- webpack version: 3.8.1
- Node.js version: 8.11.2
- Operating System: win10

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by setting PUBLIC_URL to .env :

[see advanced configuration](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#advanced-configuration)